# Правильно ли соблюдена пунктуация?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Но прежняя я, кажется, мертва.*

Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

***Но прежняя я, кажется, мертва.***

1. **Запятые расставлены верно**, но грамматику предложения и отсутствие обособления определения "прежняя" нужно правильно объяснить.
2. **Грамматическая основа**: я мертва. Сказуемое составное именное, а прилагательное "прежняя" является **предикативным определением** с двойной связью: оно согласуется со сказуемым "мертва" и подлежащим "я" (в роде и числе).

Соответственно, предикативное определение "прежняя" **не обособляется** от подлежащего, выраженного личным местоимением, с которым тесно связано.